# Language Conversion Issue For IE

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am trying to download a pdf file and making this file name as

```
return this.DownloadPDF(model, m => $"{ReportStrings.ReportName}_{1003}_{5}.pdf");
```

ReportStrings.ReportName is the name of file and when i have set my language to Japanese, the file name displayed in japanese language. When i try to download this file the file name in japanese language dispalyed correctly in firefox and chrome but it show garbled text when try to download with IE 11.

[This is the garbled text which shows for Japanese Language in IE 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDhRs.png)

What should I need to correct it?

Comment: Have you tried the things in this article?
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/928847/internet-explorer-uses-the-wrong-character-set-when-it-renders-an-html

Comment: The text is not exactly garbled. It is the UTF-8 byte array in hexadecimal notation that represents your string. You might want to notify IE of your utf-8 character set for it to display correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adwaenyth.  It helps a lot.